# Share Host VPN with Hyper-V Guest

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

I have a VPN connection on my Hyper-V Host machine.  How can I share that VPN with a Hyper-V Guest VM?

I had hoped that just sharing my LAN connection as the Virtual Network would do it, but clearly I was mistaken.  Looking at the settings in my Virtual Network, I don't see anything promising.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: how many nics are you using, is there one each for management and vm's?

Comment: @tony - I'm using just 1.  I have two physical nics available.

Answer (score 0):

The ***easy*** way is to simply connect to the host's VPN from within the guest as per standard VPN connection settings.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer - an answer would tell a way how-to accomplish it in my mind